# Highcharts column chart - transform columns manually after render

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I have a basic column chart done in Highcharts.

**I would like to 'move' (= use CSS transform: translate()) each column in the chart.**

I tried to use CSS styles to achieve this, but it obviously broke the positioning rendered by Highcharts.

**Is there any way how to change the existing elements in the callback function?**
Thank you

Code:
http://jsfiddle.net/tomexx/vrh5kzzz/10/

```
$(function () {
    var config = {
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(40,40,40,1)'
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Likes',
                'Comments',
                'Shares'
            ],
            tickColor: 'rgba(83,83,83,1)',
            gridLineColor: 'rgba(83,83,83,1)',
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            minorGridLineColor: 'rgba(83,83,83,1)',
            lineColor: 'rgba(83,83,83,1)'

        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            gridLineColor: 'rgba(83,83,83,1)',
            minorGridLineColor: 'rgba(83,83,83,1)',
            lineColor: 'rgba(83,83,83,1)'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                grouping: false,
                shadow: false,
                borderWidth: 0,
                animation: false,
                enableMouseTracking: false,
            }
        },
        series: [{
            color: 'rgba(126,200,54,1)',
            data: [44, 73, 20],
            pointPadding: 0.3,
            pointPlacement: 0.16
        }, {
            color: 'rgba(43,205,203,1)',
            data: [150, 88, 20],
            pointPadding: 0.3,
            pointPlacement: 0.04
        }, {
            color: 'rgba(168,68,214,1)',
            data: [63, 33, 10],
            pointPadding: 0.3,
            pointPlacement: -0.04
        }, {
            color: 'rgba(255,191,0,1)',
            data: [86, 245, 222],
            pointPadding: 0.3,
            pointPlacement: -0.12
        }]
    };

    $('#container').highcharts(config);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instaed of CSS styles, you can use [pointPlacement](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointPlacement) value with number.

> Since Highcharts 3.0.2, the point placement can also be numeric, where
>   0 is on the axis value, -0.5 is between this value and the previous,
>   and 0.5 is between this value and the next. Unlike the textual
>   options, numeric point placement options won't affect axis padding.

Comment: Well I use it to move the bars horizontally, but i would like to move the bars vertically as well. Each one differently. Is that possible as well? Thank you.